# Algolia aroundLatLonViaIP not returning results further away

Tags: algolia

I have a large databases of objects where I'd like to show objects that are nearer to the user searching first so I'm using `aroundLatLngViaIP`.

This works well for objects that are near by, however, if there aren't any nearby it doesn't show any further away even if there is an exact text match.

Is it possible to use `aroundLatLngViaIP` to promote results nearby but not exclude those that are far away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this, you need to use `aroundRadius: all` as an additional query parameter. Quoting from the doc:

> The special value `all` causes the geo distance to be computed and taken into account for ranking, but without filtering; this option is faster than specifying a high integer value.

https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/aroundRadius/